# server side framework for ios apps

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, wcf, spring-mvc

I am new to the IOS app development. I go through the apple developer portal they use Objective -C as their server side framework.

The main problem is I need to develop the app in one month and I know C# web service or java server side framework.

Does these frameworks are supported by the iOS apps API. Please suggest me.

And if possible give me some reference for these existing frameworks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Xamarin and mono touch to develop for iOS in C#, but there is much more to iOS development than just knowing the language.  The Cocoa frameworks are completely different to .Net and Java.  I would say you have a very big task ahead of you.  Even for an experienced developer, creating a well designed, usable, attractive app in a month is a big task

Comment: Also, iOS development would be considered client side, not server-side.  If you have an app that communicates with a server, then the server-side code can be written in anything you like - Ruby, Python, PHP, Java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually an App communicates via an HTTP service (usually a REST service) with a server. The server can be written in any language which can be used to provide a REST service. For example ASP.NET Web API if you are familiar with .NET and C#